# Switching from stored messages to real time chatting in node and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io, chat

I am new to server-side development. I'm trying to learn by doing so I'm building an application with express on the server, mongodb as my database and angularjs with twitter bootstrap on the client-side.

I dont know if this is the most practical way but when thinking about how to implement messaging between users I thought of a mongodb model called  Conversation with an id and an array of the ids of every user in the conversation and another array of strings that correspond to messages. And then add this model to my REST API.

But lets say all/some of the users in the conversation are online, why not benefit from socket.io. So how can i switch from this to real time chat? Does the interaction with mongodb occure exactly as explained and socket.io just notifies every online user that an interaction has occured? If yes, how? Or is it something else?

Comment: I'm not sure here what exactly you are talking about. But if I got it right you can use the benefit of both technologies to accomplish a real-time full chat. Socket.IO. What you mean switching from this to real time chat?

Answer (score 0):

socket.io can send real time events to connected sockets, you can use a database for storing messages that are failed to deliver and for offline users.

also, you might want to use something like Redis for this as it has channels with subscribe and publish capabilities.